# Can anyone find the next character

Tags: pattern, sequence

Question:
[image]

Options:
[image]

Patterns for you to copy paste:

```
╟ ╢ ╠ ╣ ╤ ╧ ╥

╨ ╦ ╩ ┘ ╜ ╛ ┐

╖ ╕ ╙ ╘ ┌ ╓ ╒
```

Comment: Is there a reading direction ?

Comment: @Jannis, I don't know. I did not even understand how to approach this!

Comment: I would go for finding Logic that tries to represent maths or general connect signs

Comment: i was right?!? My Logic was right?? I was pretty sure it's wrong, or this just an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it

> ┌

?
because:

> Look at the options table:
>
> ```
>   1   2   3  ...  5   6   0
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
> | ╟   ╢   ╠   ╣   ╤   ╧   ╥ |
> | ╨   ╦   ╩   ┘   ╜   ╛   ┐ |
> ```
>
> Every column corresponds to a number `1 to 7`.
>  Everything over the system is `%(modulo)7` making the last column `0`.
>  When you read the pattern top down,
>  you notice there's only one sign from each table row.
>  Also, you can calculate: `second sign - first sign = third sign`,
>  In the first case, it is `0-0=0`,
>  In the second case, it is `4-1=3`
>  and in the last case it should be `4-6=-2`.
>  I'm counting in 3rd row from right two to left and have:
>  `┌`
>  The pattern (with values):
>
> ```
> +---+---+---+
> | 0 | 1 | 4 |
> | 0 | 4 | 6 |
> | 0 | 3 | ? |
> +---+---+---+
> ```

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea how your explanation links to anything?

Comment: @Jannis, Can you explain it better please.

Comment: Okay I think I understand what you're saying, but in the case of the third column, doing what you've done in the middle column (4 - 1 = 3), you'd get (4 - 6 = ?) which would generate a negative number.

Comment: @AHKieran no, it's the other way round, namely, $6-4$.

Comment: but both the ╣ and ╘ are in the fourth column, and ╛ is in the sixth column. unless I'm misinterpreting the answer

Comment: @AHKieran you're right i messed up :)

Comment: We still got the same answer though :P

Comment: @AHKieran now my answer should :P be ┌

Comment: My answer is a riddle on it's own... i should post it here :D

Comment: @JithinPavithran thanks for editing- for formatting and retexting. :) I couldn't do better

Answer (score 1):

I think it is:

> ╕

Because:

> The middle shapes on each side (that would create a diamond if you join them up) are all T-like shapes, and the corner shapes and centre shape (arranged like a 5 on a 6 sided die) are F-like shapes. Therefore I believe the answer is limited to the F-like shapes.

And:

> As there are the three other orientations of the ╕ symbol, it seems that this orientation would be the next one in the sequence. The ┐ symbol at the start, I believe to be the last of the four other ┐ symbols if the pattern had gone on before then, so it seems right that the ╕ symbol of same orientation would go last in that sequence of shapes.